# Day of week - 4th June, 2002 using Zeller's Rule

Tags: calendar-computations

I know how to calculate day of week using Zeller's Rule, but the answer is coming as Sunday, while the correct answer is Tuesday. Where am I doing wrong? Please explain your answer step-by-step. Thanks. :)

/**** EDIT ****/

All right. I got the right answer finally. Thanks to everyone who responded. I solved it this way:

> Zeller's Rule: K + [ ( 13 * n - 1 ) / 5 ] + D + D/4 + C/4 - 2 * C
> ([Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171220131007/http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/faq.calendar.html))

- K = 4
- D = 02
- C = 20
- n = 4 (June = 4 because as per Zeller's Rule we are starting from
  March = 1, April = 2 and so on)

4 + [( 13 * 4 - 1 ) / 5] + 2 + 2/4 + 20/4 - 40

= 4 + 10 + 2 + 0 + 5 - 40

= 21 - 40

= -19

The nearest number less than -19 that is multiple of 7 is -21. So, -21 + 2 = -19. So, the remainder is 2. Starting from Sunday = 0, Monday = 1, Tuesday = 2.

Thus, answer is: **4th June, 2002 was Tuesday.**

Answer (score 1):

Zeller's rule (http://www.careeranna.com/zellers-rule-find-the-day-for-any-date-quickly/) supposes you count months from March = 1 (i.e. June = 4), which correctly gives Tuesday for your example. Incorrect Sunday answer will come if you count months from Jan = 0 (i.e. June = 5).